# Copying data from one workbook to another gets pasted in random cells

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

*Update*

I have been playing around with my code and figured out how to make the data paste in the right place the second time but then the data won't paste at all if you press the button again. Here is the updated code:

```
Dim kRow As Long
kRow = ws2.Range("W" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

If ws2.Range("W4").Value = "" Then
ws2.Range("W4").Value = ws1.Range("A4").Value
Else:
kRow = ws2.Range("W" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row - 31
ws2.Range("W" & kRow).Offset(1).Value = ws1.Range("A4").Value
End If

Dim lRow As Long
lRow = ws2.Range("V" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

If ws2.Range("V10").Value = "" Then
ws2.Range("V10").Value = ws1.Range("P2").Value
Else:
lRow = ws2.Range("V" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row - 31
ws2.Range("V" & lRow).Offset(1).Value = ws1.Range("P2").Value
End If

Dim mRow As Long
mRow = ws2.Range("Y" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

If ws2.Range("Y10").Value = "" Then
ws2.Range("Y10").Value = ws1.Range("K37").Value
Else:
mRow = ws2.Range("Y" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row - 28
ws2.Range("Y" & mRow).Offset(1).Value = ws1.Range("K37").Value
End If
```

---

Original Post

---

I'm having this annoying issue with copying and pasting data from one workbook to another. I am trying to copy some data from a user form to a master workbook that keeps all the data. I have it set up so that when then user is done with the form, they click a macro button and the master workbook opens, the data from the form gets pasted into the master workbook and then it closes. The next time the user form is filled out and the macro button is pressed, the data is pasted in the next available row in the master workbook. Most of the data I want to get transferred works except for 5 pieces of data.

The first time I press the button, everything is fine. However, if I press the button again, these five pieces of data do not get pasted in the next row as intended but it gets pasted 31 to 28 rows lower than intended. I have been trying everything to fix this but I can't seem to find the issue.

I will post the relevant code below. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
Dim kRow As Long
kRow = ws2.Range("W" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

If ws2.Range("W10").Value = "" Then
ws2.Range("W10").Value = ws1.Range("A4").Value
Else: ws2.Range("W" & kRow).Offset(1).Value = ws1.Range("A4").Value
End If

Dim lRow As Long
lRow = ws2.Range("V" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

If ws2.Range("V10").Value = "" Then
'ws2.Range("V10").Value = ws1.Range("P2").Value
Else: ws2.Range("V" & lRow).Offset(1).Value = ws1.Range("P2").Value
End If

Dim mRow As Long
mRow = ws2.Range("Y" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

If ws2.Range("Y10").Value = "" Then
ws2.Range("Y10").Value = ws1.Range("K37").Value
Else: ws2.Range("Y" & mRow).Offset(1).Value = ws1.Range("K37").Value
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the offset to 1, meaning it's taking both dimensions of the range and offsetting it by that much.

If you want it to appear in the row after last row, try `ws2.Range("Y" & mRow).Offset(1,0).Value`

Comment: Hi, I tried out your fix and that piece of data is still being pasted to Y39 instead of the next available row.

Comment: @Gintoki006 Are you trying to make new data appear in K37?

Comment: K37 is the cell from the form.